# In limSolve package, LSEI error: inequalities contradictory

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

Given a matrix, I'd like to find the linear combination of the rows that's as close as possible to some target vector. Additionally, I'd like the row weights to be nonnegative and to sum to 1. I've tried solving the problem using the limSolve package for R, but it reports an error about contradictory inequalities. Here's my function:

```
library(limSolve)

find.weights <- function(target.vector, a.matrix) {
  # parameters to the objective function
  A <- t(a.matrix)
  B <- target.vector

  # equality constraint (weights sum to 1)
  E <- matrix(rep(1, nrow(a.matrix)), nrow = 1)
  F <- 1

  # inequality constraints (all weights nonnegative)
  G <- diag(1, nrow(a.matrix))
  H <- rep(0, nrow(a.matrix))

  lsei(A = A, B = B, E = E, F = F, G = G, H = H)
}
```

Here are the inputs that are causing a problem.

target.vector:

```
[1] 0.00 0.30 0.10 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.00 0.15 0.00
```

a.matrix:

```
[1,]  0.0000000000 1.0000000 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000000           0       0
[2,]  1.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000000           0       0
[3,]  0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000000           1       0
[4,]  0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 1.0000000 0.000000000           0       0
[5,]  0.0000000000 0.6318000 0.044100000 0.2241000 0.01000000 0.0900000 0.000000000           0       0
[6,] -0.0069249820 0.4961489 0.030322369 0.1164405 0.03519697 0.3167728 0.012043447           0       0
[7,]  0.0410533877 0.2434423 0.007709501 0.0292961 0.06651868 0.5986681 0.013311866           0       0
[8,]  0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.240000000 0.7600000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000000           0       0
[9,] -0.0001006841 0.6229848 0.051032756 0.1945897 0.01236401 0.1112761 0.007853359           0       0
```

When I call the function with these inputs, I receive the aforementioned error:

```
> result <- find.weights(target.vector, a.matrix)
Warning message:
In lsei(A = A, B = B, E = E, F = F, G = G, H = H) :
  LSEI error: inequalities contradictory
```

However, the function seems to work fine if I restrict the numbers of rows or columns:

```
> result <- find.weights(target.vector, a.matrix[1:8,]) # OK
> result <- find.weights(target.vector[1:6], a.matrix[,1:6]) # OK
> result <- find.weights(target.vector[1:7], a.matrix[,1:7]) # NOPE
Warning message:
In lsei(A = A, B = B, E = E, F = F, G = G, H = H) :
  LSEI error: inequalities contradictory
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`LSEI error: inequalities contradictory`

happens when the linear constraints you specify via `E`, `F`, `G`, and `H` define a *non-feasible* problem. In other words, when there is no vector `x` that can solve all the `E %*% x == F` and `G %*% x >= H` constraints at the same time. For example, consider a problem that would  constrain two variables `x1` and `x2` such that `x1 + x2 == -1` while `x_1 >= 0` and `x2 >= 0`. Obviously, there is no `x1` and `x2` values that could meet all three constraints and the problem is infeasible.

In your problem, where `n` is the number of variables to solve for, all you are requesting is that `x_1`, `x_2`, ..., `x_n` be non-negative and that they sum to `1`. A feasible solution (among infinitely many assuming `n > 1`) is to pick `x_1 = 1` and `x_2 = ... = x_n = 0`. So a priori, `lsei` should NOT throw the error you are mentioning. As a matter of fact, your code runs fine on my machine and I am not able to reproduce the error you are seeing. Is it possible you got the error with a different code than the one you published here?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `lsei` gives spurious "inequalities contradictory".  Here's a test case:  My constraints require that solution sum to 1 (equation) and be decreasing (inequalities).

```
n <- 12
A <- diag(1, 2, n)
B <- c(1, .5)
E <- matrix(1, 1, n)
F <- 1                          # pre-set value was FALSE
G <- -diff(diag(1, n+1, n)
H <- numeric(n)
lsei(A, B, E, F, G, H)
```

This first run demonstrates that the problem is feasible.  Output:

```
$X
 [1] 0.75 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00

$residualNorm
[1] 4.440892e-16

$solutionNorm
[1] 0.125

$IsError
[1] FALSE

$type
[1] "lsei"
```

But then I change `A[1,1]`, which has nothing to do with the constraints:

```
A1 <- diag(c(1000,1),2,n)                # change one element
lsei(A=A1, B, E, F, G, H)
```

And with `A1`, which is mildly ill-conditioned, it fails:

```
$X
 [1] -2.6689062 -0.5899748  0.6479330  0.3362563  0.4279018  0.4279018
 [7]  0.4279018  0.4279018  0.4279018  0.4279018  0.4279018  0.2793792

$residualNorm
[1] 3.408485

$solutionNorm
[1] 7128401

$IsError
[1] TRUE

$type
[1] "lsei"

Warning message:
In lsei(A = A1, B = B, E = E, F = F, G = G, H = H) :
  LSEI error: inequalities contradictory
```

I think this shows that the error is bogus, i.e., this is a bug.